# weired session variables value setted in MySQL stored function

Tags: mysql

I open a MySQL Command Line Client, and type in the following SQL statements.

```
use green;
delimiter $
drop function if exists tstFunction $
create function tstFunction(cnt int) returns int
begin    
    case when 1 > cnt then set @a1 := 1;
         when 5 > cnt then set @a2 := 2;
         when 4 > cnt then set @a3 := 3;
         else set @a4 := 4;
    end case;
    return 0;
end $
delimiter ;

select tstFunction(3), @a1, @a2, @a3, @a4;
```

What I want to test is the execution flow of the CASE WHEN compound-statement. The query result of the above `SELECT` statement goes here:

```
tstFunction(3)    @a1   @a2    @a3    @a4
0                 NULL  NULL   NULL   NULL
```

I am confused of the value of `@a2`. Why `NULL`? Why not `2`?
So I open a new MySQL Command Line Client and rebuild the `tstFuncton`, but seperate the `SELECT` statement into two line like that:

```
select tstFunction(3);
select @a1, @a2, @a3, @a4;
```

And the new query result looks well:

```
@a1   @a2    @a3    @a4
NULL  2      NULL   NULL
```

What happened to the first form of `SELECT` statement? Why I need to break it into two `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, declaring local variables goes with "set" statement. In your first form of SELECT statement, you've written them directly so why you're getting NULLS.

You may have a question that you've already declared them in your function. But the thing is, executing function and printing variables are in a single SELECT statement which means they are executed as a single batch.

In the second form, as you're running both the SELECTs in two different batches, the variables come declared with values from the function.

If you want to have them coming with your first form of SELECT then declare a variable before like this,

```
set @a2 = '';
select tstFunction(3), @a1, @a2, @a3, @a4;
```

Comment: If there is a single batch for each SELECT statement, so what batch exactly means? Is there something else I need to read?

Comment: Batch means the number of statements processed at a time by the optimizer

Comment: Anyway, can I conclude the reason to be that the Optimizer has adjusted the calculation order of query fields in the first SELECT form? I mean the <tstFunction(3)> field was optimized to be calculated later than other three ones.